# how to insert html in php then php in html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I wanna insert HTML in PHP, next PHP in HTML. I'dont know how can I do this.

```
<div class="popular-posts">
            <?php 
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();

<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full' ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>

endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you googled it ??

Comment: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/php_with_html.htm

Comment: close php tag after while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    <div class="popular-posts">
    <?php 
    $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'meta_key' =>   'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
    while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();

    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full' ); ?>

    <a href="<?= get_permalink(); ?>"><?= the_title() ?></a>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the file extension must be in (dot)php.

To insert HTML in PHP, you just need to write with 'echo'. I.e :

```
<html>
<body>
<p>write in html</p>
<?php
    echo '<h1>Write in PHP</h1>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You can't write PHP code in HTML file. But you can write PHP code inside element of HTML, the file extension must be in (dot)php. I.e :

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
    $color = 'yellow';
?>
<h1 style="color:<?php echo $color; ?>">Example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Visit http://www.w3schools.com/ to learn more about HTML and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your first opened PHP tag and then you opened another PHP... and also you didnot open for the last statement `"endwhile;"`

```
<div class="popular-posts">
            <?php 
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
?>

<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'full' ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>

<?php
endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

And the general syntax to use PHP in HTML is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     <?php
        // Your PHP Code
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And to use HTML in PHP...

```
    <?php
      //Your PHP Code
    ?>
     <!-- Your HTML Tags -->
    <?php
    ?>
```

or else you can also try like this...

```
<?php
  //Your PHP Code
echo "<ul><li>Some Text</li></ul>";
  ?>
```